# Refresh Xamarin View while debugging without rebuild of app

Tags: xamarin

In Visual Studio (2015) using an Android Emulator, is there a way I can make a minor update to a xaml view, and have that refreshed in the debugging application without having to rebuild and re-deploy the project?

Currently a build/deploy for debugging takes about 2 minutes, and having to make some minor UI style tweak and do the whole thing again is driving me nuts.

I suppose I'm asking if there's some ASP.NET MVC-like functionality where I can update a frontend file (cshtml, js, etc) and just refresh the page without reloading the project.

Comment: https://www.xamarin.com/live It does have its own limitations, be sure to read the Limitation section: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks

Comment: @SushiHangover - this is pretty much what I was after (ability to edit paddings and such to fine-tune).  Assuming there's nothing else available (I'm guessing not), toss it in an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Xamarin Live Player lets you make live edits to your app and have those changes reflected live on your device. Your code runs inside the Xamarin Live Player app – there is no need to set up emulators or to use cables to deploy the code!

- https://www.xamarin.com/live

It does have limitations, be sure to read the Limitation section:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live